# Как правильно говорить: «вряд ли» или «врят ли»?

Tags: фонетика

Оглушать ли согласный на конце написанного слова или рассматривать его как единое целое с частицей "ли"?

Answer (score 1):

Перед сонорными согласными **не происходит озвончения** шумных глухих согласных (слово [сл`ова]).

Есть такая частица ВРЯД, в которой в позиции конца слова происходит оглушение [ВР'AT]. При появлении частицы ЛИ ничего не изменилось: озвончения не происходит, произносим [ВР'АТ] ЛИ. Рассматривать надо "как единое целое с частицей ЛИ".

Comment: Но ведь если рассматривать ВРЯД ЛИ "как единое целое", то конец этого целого находится после ЛИ, а не после ВРЯД, а там уже оглушаться нечему. И разве вообще существует слово ВРЯД без ЛИ?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, многими это "ВРЯД ЛИ" действительно воспринимается как сросшееся сочетание, которое подчиняется фонетике единого слова. А оглушения звонких перед сонорными не происходит. 
Так что звонкое Д возможно как минимум в быстрой речи.
Но при четкой артикуляции Д все-таки оглушается.

Answer (score 0):

Точно глухая, как и в случае "орудия в ряд лафетами блестят". 
(здесь не оглушение происходит, а имеет место изначальное выговаривание согласного "т")

Comment: Изначальное выговаривание согласного "т" - если вы о слове "блестят", то да, а если о слове "ряд", то там как раз изначально было "д": ряды, рядов... На конце слова "д" превращается в "т". Это и называется "оглушение"

Comment: Я говорю о слове "ряд" (именительный падеж). Оно уверенно произносится как "рят" даже перед словами, начинающимися с гласной (напр. "ряд ополченцев"). Перед словами, начинающимися с некоторых звонких согласных, звук "т" переходит в "д" даже в словах, заканчивающихся на букву "т" (ряд зубов; рот закрыт - тоже звук "д" в первои слове) - по физиологическим причинам. Но такой модификации не происходит перед "л": слова "метла" и "быдло" произносятся с теми согласными, с которыми записываются (соотв., с "т" и "д") - нет причин, затрудняющих произношение со звуком, соответствующим букве.

Answer (score 0):

Точно глухая, как и в случае "орудия в ряд лафетами блестят".